# How to hide previous button while navigating to first one in review?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing one application in which user can review the answers after giving answer of quiz.user can review either after completion of whole game or can review in between(meaning without completiong whole game).While reviewing answers there are previous and next buttons from which user can go to previous and next questions.when there is first question previous button should be hidden.for that i have written following code.

```
-(IBAction)btn_Next:(id)sender
{

    isPrv=NO;
    nextcnt=nextcnt+1;
    if(nextcnt==[arrReview count]-1)
    {
        isCheck=YES;
    }

    Option1.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option2.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option3.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option4.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option5.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

    btnPrevious.hidden=FALSE;
    if(reviewcount<[arrReview count]-1)
    {   
        [self Explantion_Refrences];
        reviewcount++;
        [self Review];
    }
    else
    {
        [self Explantion_Refrences];
        btnNext.hidden=TRUE;

    }

}

 -(IBAction)btn_Previous:(id)sender
{

   nextcnt=nextcnt-1;

    Option1.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option2.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option3.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option4.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    Option5.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

       if( reviewcount>0)
    {
         reviewcount--;
        [self Review];


    }
    else
    {
         btnPrevious.hidden=TRUE;

    }

}

-(IBAction)Review
{


    if(nextcnt==1 && isPrv)
    {
        [btnPrevious setHidden:YES];
        nextcnt=0;


    }
}
```

I am incrementing nextcount when user presses the nextquestion and decrementing it when user presses previous button.this works fine when user go to last question by pressing next and after that go to first question.but if user goes to one next question or 2 next question and after that go to first question.this is not working.Previous button is visible.Does anyone know that how can i resolve this?Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get which of your variables contain which information so adapt the following to your needs:

```
btnNext.hidden      = (currentQuestionNumber == questionsArray.count-1) ? YES : NO;
btnPrevious.hidden  = (currentQuestionNumber == 0) ? YES : NO;
```